# height of an element javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to adjust the size of an element in the opposite direction, so the code below does adjust it, but it enlarges it from current position to bottom, I want current position to top. What would be an efficient way of doing this? thanks

```
var ele=document.getElementById('mydiv');
ele.style.height = 500+'px';
```

Answer (score 1):

Do what you're doing, then move the element up by its original height:

```
var ele=document.getElementById('mydiv');
ele.style.height = 500+'px';
ele.style.top -= 100+'px'; //or whatever the height originally was.
```

Comment: I know its a given but you should include "position: absolute".