# set height div javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm adjusting the height of the box with no problems, now I would like to adjust the height of the box grabbing the top handle and adjust height but upwards. What would be a good way of doing this? thanks

(current downwards code)

```
var mY = event.clientY; 
var originalHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById('somediv').style.height);

if(click == 1){ // down
            var sY = event.clientY; 
            var finalHeight = originalHeight +sY-mY;
            document.getElementById('somediv').style.height=finalHeight + 'px';
}else{ // up
    resize upwards instead of downwards....
}
```

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517407/height-of-an-element-javascript/517440#517440

Comment: Are you meaning for both mY and sY to equal event.clientY?  If that's true, then sY-mY = 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

An element's position is defined by its top-left corner - you'll have to move it up at the same time as you extend it from the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Resizing a DIV "up" is not as easy as resizing it "down".  The reason is that when you specify a HEIGHT, the DIV will expand "down" as its normal flow.  The top left corner of the DIV will remain static.

Allowing the DIV to be resized "UP" will give you a lot of issues.  In order to do this, you will need to set the HEIGHT, then the POSITION of the DIV to currentHeight - previousHeight.  You will notice it will jitter a lot when doing this.

Also, anything above your DIV will need to be displayed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and the jQuery [Dimensions plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dimensions).